# Jar файл в Intellij Idea

Tags: java, jar, intellij-idea, jetbrains

Не подскажите, как создать jar-файл через UI Intellij Idea (JetBrains)?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Завит от того, какая версия *Idea*.

До 9.0 идём `Build` → `Build Jars`.

В *IDEA 9.0*, соответственно, `Project Structure` → `Artifacts`.

В 10 не знаю, но, скорее всего, также должно быть.

А вообще для таких вещей есть [ant](http://ant.apache.org/), [maven](http://maven.apache.org/)...

Comment: Спасибо, не могла найти, как это сделать в Idea 9.0. А про ант и т.д. известная вещь.

Answer (score 3):

Пошаговая инструкция:

- <kbd>Intellij Idea</kbd> >>> <kbd>File</kbd> >>> <kbd>Project Structure</kbd> >>> 
  <kbd>Artifacts</kbd>
- Нажимаете + Выбираете >>><kbd>JAR</kbd> >>> 
  <kbd>From modules with dependencies</kbd> >>> <kbd>Main Clas</kbd>
- Выбираете Main >>> установите галочку на 
  `extract to output target JAR` >>> <kbd>OK</kbd> >>> 
  В `Output directry` выберите где будет находится файл
- Установите галочку `Include in project build` >>>
  установите галочку `Show content of element` >>> <kbd>Apply</kbd> >>><kbd>OK</kbd>

---

Затем заходим во вкладку <kbd>Build</kbd> >>> <kbd>Build Artifact</kbd> >>>
выбираете свой проект и жмете <kbd>Build</kbd>